# NameError: name 'names' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently working on a simple Oregon Trail clone for a school project. I want to use Tkinter for this game, since the current version for pygame only goes up to Python 2 and I am used to using Python 3. I separated the different parts of the game into separate py files (main.py, names.py, occupations.py, store.py, game.py) and put them all into a folder so it is more organized. I already typed out the code for the welcome screen and the code for main.py, names.py, and a little for occupations.py. When I run my code, I am presented with an error that that the name 'names' is not defined. In the names file, I created a function called names() and a ran it in the main file. What is wrong with my code?

---

```
# main.py
from tkinter import *
from names import *
from occupations import *
from store import *
from game import *

root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
root.wm_title('Oregon Trail')
root.geometry("200x75")

canvas = Canvas(root,width=400,height=200)
canvas.pack()

welcome = Label(canvas,
                font = ('System',14,'bold'),
                text = 'Oregon Trail')
welcome.grid(row=0,sticky=(N,S,E,W))

play = None
def playbuttoncommands():
    canvas.pack_forget()
    play.grid_forget()
    welcome.grid_forget()
    names()
play = Button(canvas,
              font = 'System',
              text = 'Travel the Trail',
              command = playbuttoncommands)
play.grid(row=1,sticky=(N,S,E,W))

root.mainloop()
```

---

```
# names.py
from tkinter import *
from occupations import *
from store import *
from game import *
from main import *

def names():
    canvas2 = Canvas(root,width=400,height=200)
    canvas.pack()

    root.geometry("400x200")

    namelabel = Label(root,
                      font = 'System',
                      text = 'Please enter the names of your travel group:')
    namelabel.grid(row=1,sticky=N)

    name1 = ''
    name1entry = Entry(root,textvariable=name1)
    name1entry.grid(row=2,sticky=N)

    name2 = ''
    name2entry = Entry(root,textvariable=name2)
    name2entry.grid(row=3, sticky=N)

    name3 = ''
    name3entry = Entry(root,textvariable=name3)
    name3entry.grid(row=4,sticky=N)

    name4 = ''
    name4entry = Entry(root,textvariable=name4)
    name4entry.grid(row=5,sticky=N)

    name5 = ''
    name5entry = Entry(root,textvariable=name5)
    name5entry.grid(row=6,sticky=N)

    enternames = Button(text = 'Continue', command = submitnames)
    enternames.grid(row=7,sticky=N)
```

---

```
# occupations.py
from tkinter import *
from names import *
from store import *
from game import *
from main import *

def submitnames():
        name1 = name1entry.get()
        name2 = name2entry.get()
        name3 = name3entry.get()
        name4 = name4entry.get()
        name5 = name5entry.get()
```

---

```
# Full Error Report
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File ***************/main.py", line 33, in playbuttoncommands
    names()
NameError: name 'names' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a circular import, because main.py imports names.py, which then imports main.py.  You should avoid these, as they cause problems like you are seeing. (The error report doesn't show all those layers, did you leave some out?)

Organize your code so that if moduleA imports moduleB, then moduleB doesn't need to import moduleA.

BTW: "from xyz import *" is discouraged, because it makes it hard to see where names were defined.